# How to implement dynamic sql function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am using `PostgreSQL 11` version.

I want to implement a function that takes the layer name (table), column name, and id as parameters.

```
create or replace function test(layer_name anyelement, field_name anyelement, object_id text)
   returns setof anyelement
   language plpgsql
as $function$
   begin 
       return query execute format('
           select 
            *
           from
            %s
           where
            %s = cast($1 as int4)'
    , pg_typeof(layer_name), pg_typeof(field_name))
    using object_id;
end;
$function$
;
```

This is the code I've implemented and when I call the function I get an error.

What am I doing wrong?

#### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "="

Where: PL/pgSQL function test(anyelement,anyelement,text) line 3 at RETURN QUERY

```
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select * from test(?, ?, ?)
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "="
  Where: PL/pgSQL function test(anyelement,anyelement,text) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "="
  Where: PL/pgSQL function test(anyelement,anyelement,text) line 3 at RETURN QUERY}
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "="
  Where: PL/pgSQL function test(anyelement,anyelement,text) line 3 at RETURN QUERY


### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select * from test(?, ?, ?)
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "="
  Where: PL/pgSQL function test(anyelement,anyelement,text) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "="
  Where: PL/pgSQL function test(anyelement,anyelement,text) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Comment: What is `layer` and why you are using pg_`typeof(layer_name)`?

Comment: The code makes too little sense for me to understand. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: layer is table. pg_typeof seems to be misused.

Comment: I want to make a function that takes the table name, the column name of the conditional clause, and the condition ID as parameters and returns the result.

Comment: @Hans You are very close. Just few things need to be changed. Added answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your function slightly

1. Instead of `field_name anyelement` use `field_name text` in parameter.
2. and in place of  `pg_typeof(field_name)` use only `field_name`:

So your function definition will be:

```
create or replace function test(layer_name anyelement, field_name text, object_id text)
   returns setof anyelement
   language plpgsql
as $function$
   begin 
       return query execute format('
           select 
            *
           from
            %s
           where
            %s = cast($1 as int4)'
    , pg_typeof(layer_name), field_name)
    using object_id;
end;
$function$
;
```

Most important part is calling of the function:

```
select * from test(null::table_name,'field_name','2');
```

Please note that your `field_name` always should be `integer` type and `object_id` should be number only because you are casting it to `integer`.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=120f2d72d1b744199d2985b6a534b076)

Comment: I don't know what null:: means but It worked very successfully. thank you

Comment: For the sake of completeness:
::<datatype> casts something to a specific datatype. Casting a null value to a datatype simply is the easiest way to get a value of a specific datatype. Casting for example an integer to other data types requires some kind of calculations to be done. And these calculations are different for each data type or impossible for e.g. a timestamp. Casting nulls to anything is easy.